# Uploading Database to phpMyAdmin doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I checked out a Wordpress site from SVN to run it locally and uploaded the SQL file in phpMyAdmin. But when I am going to http://localhost/projectName/index.php it is taking me to setup new wordpress, which I am obviously not expecting. Can anybody tell what wrong am I doing?

Comment: try to delete wp-admin -> install.php

Comment: No help! Still doing the same!

Comment: if you are accessing your webfolder with Filezilla make sure you set the permissions to min 477 on install.php before deleting it, otherwise it will "show" the file as deleted but when you refresh the view it will reappear.

Comment: I have the same problem right now. I solved it. The database data wasn't uploaded correct. I did it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a wp-config.php in the wordpress root directory?  If not, copy the wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php and edit it to reflect the mysql setup

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'my_database_name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'mydatabase_user');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_database_password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

In phpmyadmin, make sure there is a database with the right name, and that the database tables were uploaded correctly (e.g. not a blank database)

Also in phpmyadmin select the database user and make sure they have permissions to access this database.  Let me know if the above fixes it thanks

Comment: Yes I was supposed to configure the wp-config file. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Remember that moving WordPress is not just about the wp-config.php. Links and information are held in the database - click this link to see how to complete the move http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-safely-move-wordpress/ - as you have already done the second half of this "how to move WordPress" make sure you have also done the first half :)

Answer (score 0):

...check if the table prefix ($table_prefix) is the same on wp_config.php and on the database.